# R - Confidence intervals for proportion of zero in a stratified random sample

Tags: confidence-interval, standard-error, proportion, survey

I'm putting together prevalence estimates and CIs for the results of a stratified SRS survey, for which I've already computed weights. The strata are 5 different regions, each observed over time, and the outcome is binary. Currently I'm putting together a pooled estimate and state-level estimates for each sampling frame using:

```
for (w in unique(df$window)) {
  dfw = df[df$window == w, ]
  wsvy = svydesign(ids=dfw$psu, strata=dfw$region, weights=dfw$pweight, data=dfw, fpc=dfw$N_window)
  pooled_prop = svyciprop(~I(y > 0), wsvy, level=0.95)
  state_prop = svyby(~I(y > 0), ~region, design=wsvy, svyciprop, vartype="ci", level=0.95) %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, round, digits=4)
  print(w)
  print(round(as.vector(pooled_prop), digits=4))
  print(round(attr(pooled_prop, "ci"), digits=4))
  print(state_prop)
}
```

This is all well and good, except that for a handful of sample frames, there were regions with 0 instances of the outcome variable (i.e. the observed proportion = 0). So a point estimate of 0 is fine here, but I want to also have reasonable confidence intervals, which are apparently [not possible using svyciprop](https://r-survey.r-forge.r-project.org/survey/html/svyciprop.html)

Does anyone know a method in R for producing confidence intervals for surveys when the observed proportion is 0 or 1?

Answer (score 1):

In general, the problem is that it's hard to bound the design effect at all when all the observed values are zero (which is why `svyciprop` doesn't).

When you only have stratified element sampling and no clustering it should be possible, though it's still not easy.  Suppose, for example, that there are non-zero values in the population, but only in one stratum. Suppose that sample size in that stratum is $n_1$ from a population $N_1$. The rule of three says a good upper confidence limit on the proportion $p_1$ in that stratum is $3/n_1$, which translates to $(N_1/N)(3/n_1)$ in the population, or $(3/N)(N_1/n_1)$.

I think this bound, applied to the stratum with the lowest sampling fraction, gives the worst case (at least if all the sampling fractions are small), so I think that's the best upper confidence limit you can produce if you don't know anything about how the probabilities might differ across strata.